# Is it necessary to modify my SQLite database for use in android app?

Tags: android, sqlite

I got my sqlite database which has some data on it, but i read in this blog (http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) that the tables must have a row called _id so android can bind the field (not sure what that means) but i find this pretty troublesome since its a little complex database, so I was wondering if i really have to modify my database or there is another way to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `CursorAdapter`, or any of its subclasses, your `Cursor` must have an `_id` integer column, preferably one that is unique.

Your choices are:

1. Add `_id` (e.g., as an `AUTOINCREMENT` column) to your tables and include that in your queries
2. Rename some column, such as SQLite's `ROWID`, in your tables in the query (e.g., `SELECT ROWID AS _id, ... FROM table WHERE ...`), as what matters is what is in the `Cursor`
3. Try returning a fixed value for `_id` (e.g., `SELECT _id=0, ... FROM table WHERE ...`), though I have never tried this and have no idea if it works
4. Do not use `CursorAdapter` or any of its subclasses

Comment: So if i add the _id row in my tables, and i don't declare it as a primary key, it would still work as planned or it should be a primary key?

Comment: @sebastianhrp: I think `AUTOINCREMENT` has to be used on a primary key. However, I had forgotten about `ROWID` -- see updated item #2 in the list.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can definitely keep using your db.

As for the "_id" field, it is used in many Adapters for them to find the correct place where to position your items (for instance in Lists and Spinners), but there are workarounds for it's absence too, and they it's required for just accessing your data.

A common solution for the missing _id, btw is to rename the index of your rows (if it exists and is not called "_id") with a query like:

```
SELECT index AS _id IN table;
```

Hope this helps.